# swig.compileFile result cached even with { cache: false } opts set

Tags: node.js, caching, swig-template

I'm writing an application that uses swig directly. 
I don't need swig caching and I wouldn't like to call `swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });`.

So I try to call swig.compileFile(url, { cache: false }); , the problem is that the template appears to be always cached. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: (I am the creator of Swig templates) I just verified that everything is working fine as you expect that it should be. Are you sure you're using the latest version (1.2.2)? Can you post a barebones test-case that shows all of the code that produces the issue?

Comment: Oh, as in the answer below, it looks like I read your question incorrectly as well. It looks like you're //trying// to call swig.setDefaults and it's not working. You should file an issue on GitHub for this, or (preferably) submit a pull request.

Answer (score 1):

Code https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/v1.2.2/lib/swig.js#L608

Don't know why there is no code accessing to `options.cache`, now I think it is more like a bug, or at least not good api design, because the document mention about multi-level options

---

Another option is clear cache in memory before compiling:

```
swig.invalidateCache();
var template = swig.compileFile('index.html');
```

Comment: But I know that swig.setDefaults({ cache: false });. From the documentation I understood that it was also possible to call swig.compileFile(url, { cache: false }); instead of setting defaults.

Comment: They did say that use multi-level options, but the code say NO :), It a bug?

Comment: @damphat see [line 619](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/v1.2.2/lib/swig.js#L619) and subsequently [line 179](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/v1.2.2/lib/swig.js#L179)

Comment: @robertklep Can you see where they assign `options parameter` to `this.options` or `self.options`?

Comment: @damphat [line 124](https://github.com/paularmstrong/swig/blob/v1.2.2/lib/swig.js#L124)

Comment: @robertklep but the question is about `swig.compileFile(url, { cache: false });`, not about `swig.setDefaults({ cache: false })`, he said he don't like to use `swig.setDefaults`, am I missing something?

Comment: You saved my life voting up :)